# Support Landscape for one UIViewController and Portrait for Others in UINavigationController Stack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have 4 UIViewControllers -- Named as ControllerA,ControllerB,ControllerC,ControllerD.

Where ControllerA is RootViewController in UINavigationStack.

```
ControllerA *ca = [[ControllerA alloc]initWithNibName:@"ControllerA" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nv = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:ca];
self.window.rootViewController = nv;
```

After this is pushed ControllerB ,they are both in potrait,but problem comes here i want controllerC in landscape.

I have gone through many Codes,but any satisfactory or working solution but i did manage to rotate it by transforming view along angle --

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]]setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
animated:YES];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

But now i want to present modally ControllerD on controllerC and it doesNot coming in landscape if it does by some rotation , it will disturb all other viewcontroller transform .

After doing so much , i came back on same problem of making ControllerC in landscape by some documented method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Portrait Mode VC,

```
#pragma mark iOS 5 Orientation Support

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

#pragma mark iOS 6 Orientation Support

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

For Landscape mode VC,

```
#pragma mark - iOS 5.0 and up Rotation Methods

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

#pragma mark - iOS 6.0 and up Rotation Methods

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: Karthika this will not force one Controller in landscape because When controllers in navigation stack , they follow their root view controller , if root view is potrait then all will be in potrait and if it is in landscape then all will be in landscape.

Comment: in my application, my first,second,third view controller is portrait. in fourth view controller is in landscape mode. i have handled orientation in each view controller like this. and in Plist all orientations are in enable state.

Comment: Mam when is doing this it is coming in landscape --  SecondScreen *ss = [[SecondScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondScreen" bundle:nil];[self.navigationController presentViewController:ss animated:YES completion:nil]; but not when i am pushing it on uinavigationcontroller. is there anything else i need to do .

Comment: Thanks, i made it work according to your answer , but it still not working with navigation , but yes without its working . Thanks a Lot

Comment: check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645782/force-orientation-to-portrait-mode/18649684#18649684. try this for using UINavigationController category.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36932/discussion-between-kshitij-godara-and-karthika)